# What is .tip file in lucene?

Tags: lucene

What will be stored in .tip file? Is FST for a field is stored? Will it be updated during the changes in the index? Or will it be created again? Is the same FST used for AnalyzingInfizSuggestor and prefixQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene62/package-summary.html#package.description) and more [docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50PostingsFormat.html) :)

`Term Index .tip    The index into the Term Dictionary`

### Term Index

The .tip file contains an index into the term dictionary, so that it can be accessed randomly. See BlockTreeTermsWriter for more details on the format.